# Why implicit conversion is not applied to second argument?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, implicit

When I try to compile the following code

```
case class A(x: Int = 0)

object Conversions {
  case class Converter[T](c: T) {
    def +[U](that: Converter[U]): String = "worked"
  }
  implicit def convert(c: A): Converter[A] = Converter[A](c)
  implicit def convert(c: Int): Converter[Int] = Converter[Int](c)
}

object Main extends App {
    import Conversions._
    val a: String = A() + A()
    val b: String = 1 + A() // FAIL
    val c: String = A() + 1
    val d: Int = 1 + 1
}
```

I get the following error message

> error: type mismatch; found: A; required: String

What is the difference between `Int` and `A`, so that expression `b` fails, while `a` and `c` pass? What do I do to make it compile?

Answer (score 1):

First, the *difference* is that `Int` already has another `+` method, which expects another `Int` and returns an `Int`;
If you add a similar method to `A` you'd get similar failures:

```
case class A(x: Int = 0) {
  // this would be similar to Int's plus operation:
  def +(other: A): A = A(x + other.x)
}

// now these would behave "symmetrically": 
val a: A = A() + A()
val b: String = 1 + A() // FAIL
val c: String = A() + 1 // FAIL
val d: Int = 1 + 1
```

As for why that fact causes this specific failure - that's trickier, I assume it has to do with the order in which the compiler tries to "choose" the right implicit conversion based on the left and right argument.

Comment: But `A()` is not Int!

Comment: I didn't claim `A` is an `Int` - I merely showed that if `A`, like `Int`, had a binary operator called `+` - they would behave similarly.

Comment: Yes, but this second failure might have different mechanism. I've made a version of the code where there was no second overload for `Int.+(Int)`, and it still didn't compile. Either I've made a mistake, or your explanation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the arithmetic `+` operator with, say `plus`:

```
def plus[U](that: Converter[U]): String = "worked"
```

your implicit conversions should work the way you expect:

```
val a = A() plus A()  // worked
val b = 1 plus A()    // worked
val c = A() plus 1    // worked
val d = 1 plus 1      // worked
```

Rather than a direct implicit conversion between `Int` and `A`, your implicit conversions are between `Int` and class `Converter` (and, between `A` and `Converter`).  The compiler apparently is having a hard time sorting through the conversion rules between `Int` and `A` when it sees a `+` method well defined for `Int` – unless you provide a direct implicit conversion between `Int` and `A` like in the following example:

```
object A {
  implicit def intToA(n: Int): A = A(n)
}

case class A(x: Int = 0) {
  def +(that: A): A = A(this.x + that.x)
}

val a = A(1) + A(2)  // A(3)
val b = 1 + A(1)     // A(2)
val c = A() + 1      // A(1)
val d = 1 + 1        // 2
```

Comment: Both `A` and `Int` are not from my library. I cannot convert `Int` to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clear understanding on why this attempt was successful, but I hope that it will be useful to other users. Here I'm matching on both arguments at the same time to minimize Scala's attempts to bruteforce correct tree of implicit conversions.

```
object Defs {
    case class A(x: Int = 1)
    case class B(x: Int = 2)

    trait IsExpr[T] {
        def conv(v: T): Int
    }

    implicit object aIsExpr extends IsExpr[A] {
        override def conv(v: A): Int = v.x
    }

    implicit object bIsExpr extends IsExpr[B] {
        override def conv(v: B): Int = v.x
    }

    implicit def canSum1[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ca: IsExpr[A], cb: IsExpr[B]): Int = ca.conv(a) + cb.conv(b)
    implicit def canSum2[A](a: A, b: Int)(implicit ca: IsExpr[A]): Int = ca.conv(a) + b
    implicit def canSum3[A](a: Int, b: A)(implicit ca: IsExpr[A]): Int = a + ca.conv(b)

    implicit def convert[A](a: A) = new {
        def +[B](b: B)(implicit f: (A, B) => Int): Int = f(a, b)
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    import Defs._
    val a: Int = A() + A()
    val b: Int = 1 + A()
    val c: Int = A() + 1
    val d: Int = 1 + 1
}
```